# Android : Text Fields are displaying empty when returning to previous activity

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I have a problem with back button functionality in an `Activity` of Android. The first `Activity` having the `Spinner` to select one item from the `Spinner's` list and second one is the text field. I implemented search functionality using the `Spinner` and text field. The results are displaying fine as a `ListView`.

Here my Problem is:

**While returning to the first `Activity`, the `Spinner` and text field are showing empty in the `Activity`. It should show the previous searched results.**

Help me with the sample code/ links.

Comment: have you finished your first activity before move to next activity ?

Comment: how to finish the first activity?

Comment: How do you go back? Are you calling `finish()` while going back?

Comment: @ Shafi yes, i am calling the back function using Intent as **Intent i=new Intent (presentClass.this, previousClass.class);**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dont create a new intent. You just need to call `finish()` from your second Activity to handle back event and move back to your first activity.

Answer (score 1):

Its normal. When your first Activity goes to back ground its finished by System itself. So make sure to save your data in some place and in Activitie's `onCreate()` and `onRestart()` method reload the data to TextView and spinner..

**Edits:**
Create a Data class and Store your search results in String[] array or a String or how ever you like it. and make the class a singlton class. and when you come back to this screen fetch those data's and set Text of TextView and adapter for Spinner..

> Shafi yes, i am calling the back function using Intent as Intent i=new
>   Intent (presentClass.this, previousClass.class);

Don't do this. Because the Activity stack will become like loop with same Activities started again n again. Instead just finish **presentClass**.. it will come back to **previousClass**

Answer (score 1):

Just an addition to @ntc post look to `onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState)` and `onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle state)` methods in Activity.